# How can I put literal $ in sublime-completions file?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, dollar-sign

I want to put literal $ in sublime-completions file. I tried first

```
{ "trigger": "request", "contents": "\$$1 = request('$1');" }
```

but this seems malformed. It corrupts the whole file. So I tried

```
{ "trigger": "request", "contents": "$$1 = request('$1');" }
```

this doesn't corrupt other snippets, but doesn't work neither. When I type in req[tab], 'req' disappears.

How can I put literal $ in completions file?
(I know it works in seperate sublime-snippet file, but I want to organize things.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may seem strange but here's how it should be:

```
{ "trigger": "request", "contents": "\\$$1 = request('$1');" }
```

So `$` is `\\$`.

Just in case, `\\$0` will output `$0`

Comment: Remember to accept answers that answer your question and welcome to SO!

Comment: Vlakarados: Oh, I see. I didn't know!